# Vector3.Slerp() stops without finishing what it has to do

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i wanted to make the player to go somewhere but i don't want it to look like it's teleporting so i used Vector3.Slerp but the problem is it's not going to target it stops halfway.

Here is the code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(GoToTargetPos());
    }
} IEnumerator GoToTargetPos()
{
    Vector3 targetPos = transform.position + offset;

    transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.75f);

    isDone = true;
}
```

Sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: Can you post the code to show how GoToTargetPos() is being called

Comment: Yeah please wait

Comment: @AquaDev add that to your question.

Comment: @AquaDev also, your IEnumerator is only offseting the player a little bit. you are never completing the slerp

Comment: @ryeMoss i edited my question you can look at where it is being called

Comment: @Eddge ok i did it

Comment: Why are you starting a new coroutine every frame as long as space is pressed? - that's not how you should use coroutines. Also every single coroutine executes `Vector3.Slerp` exactly once (and then sleeps)

Comment: @UnholySheep it isnt every frame its pressed it is the frame it first got pressed(not held).  if it was `Input.GetKey` it would be every frame it was held down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer, just to show it working...

```
IEnumerator GoToTargetPos()
{
    Vector3 targetPos = transform.position + offset;
    float timeElapsed = 0.0f;
    float timeToMove = 0.75f; // Using this since that is how you are waiting...
    while(timeElapsed < timeToMove)
    {
       timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
       float ratio = Mathf.Clamp01(timeElapsed / timeToMove);
       transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos, ratio);

       yield return null; // Return to this at the beginning of the next frame
    }
    isDone = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i would have headaches now if you wouldn't answer it !!

Comment: @AquaDev Make sure you take some time to understand how it works, the while loop keeps the coroutine running until it is complete.  without it, it would only work for 1 pass and not do what you intended it to do.

Comment: yeah i understood it at first :D, Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Using `Slerp` in a Coroutine is an bad idea I think...

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) I would recommend using `Slerp` in the `Update`:

Try this:

```
public class Moving : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 offset;
    public float offsetTime = 2.0f;
    private float t = 0.0f;
    private bool moveMe = false;
    private Vector3 targetPos;
    private Vector3 startPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        targetPos = transform.position + offset;
        startPos = transform.position;
        StopMoving();
    }

    public void StartMoving()
    {
        t = 0.0f;
        moveMe = true;
    }

    private void StopMoving()
    {
        t = 0.0f;
        moveMe = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (moveMe)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime / offsetTime;

            if(t < 1.0f)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(startPos, targetPos, t);
            }
            else
            {
                StopMoving();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: For his case he wants to move the player by time (`Time.deltaTime`) and the `Coroutine` is async. `Time.deltaTime * speed` is not save I think. `The parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1].`

Comment: coroutines will return depending on how he yields, if he does `yields return new waitforendofframe` the coroutine will return at the end of the next frame, if he `yield return null` it will return at the beginning of the next frame, and he can use Time.deltaTime in a coroutine.

Comment: As @Eddge said, using `Slerp` in a coroutine function is not a bad idea. The link you provided in your answer did not mention that. That statement is misleading.